# can apply Address operator to 2d array of not integral type and not integral field of struct in C?

Tags: c, struct, operator-keyword, multidimensional-array, memory-address

I read a **C book**, it says that, if we just can apply address operator to element of 2d array of integral types (e.g. short, int, long). For example, if type is float, then we must use a temp variable. Code Example:

```
int i, j;
int arr[4][4];
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
       scanf("%d", &a[i][j]); /* OK because of int type */
```

But this is not OK:

```
int i, j;
float arr[4][4];
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
       scanf("%f", &a[i][j]); /* NOT OK because of float type - not integral type */
```

We have to use temp variable:

```
int i, j;
float temp;
float arr[4][4];
for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j) {
       scanf("%f", &temp); /* OK */
       a[i][j] = temp;     /* then assign back to element of 2d array */
   }
```

The author says the same probblem with struct having not integral fields.

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    int id;
    float grade;
} Student;
```

...

```
Student s;
float temp;
scanf("%d", &s.id);        /* OK becuase of integral type */
/* scanf("%f", &s.grade);  NOT OK because of float type */
scanf("%f", &temp);  /* OK */
s.grade = temp;      /* assign back */
```

The author just says in C, it is that but does not explain. This is strange, i have never heard of this before, as i test program on Visual Studio 6.0, Visual Studio 2010 (add new file with .c extension), it works normally without need to use temp variable

Is it a problem of history - old C style? 

And is there this limitation in C++?

Comment: Mentioning the name of the book might help us in **not** recommending it to anyone in future. :)

Comment: Also, your code doesn't compile because the array `a[4][4]` isn't declared; the array `arr[4]4]` **is**.

Comment: @AlokSave as far as that goes, the *author* would probably be good to put on the avoid-at-all-costs list.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider finding a new author:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i, j;
    float arr[4][4];
    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j < 2; ++j)
            scanf("%f", &arr[i][j]);

    for (i=0;i<2;++i)
        for (j=0;j<2;++j)
            printf("%f\n", arr[i][j]);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
1.01
2.01
3.01
4.01
```

**Output**

```
1.010000
2.010000
3.010000
4.010000
```

Perhaps more info on what his/her reasons are would be helpful, but barring anything with some real meat for such a claim, I'd line my bird cage with that book. There *may* be something to the history behind his claim. The only thing I can fathom would be relevant is that  nature of `float` (i.e. the implementation-specific nature of it). Most everyone uses IEEE 754 single-prec for `float`, double-prec for `double`. But I'm granting him a *lot* of latitude in trying to understand his logic for that claim.

Comment: The history, if such there is, has to pre-date K&R 1st Edition in 1978.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I would think so.